# Chaining methods in Ruby, and injecting a block into the chain

Tags: ruby

Consider the following Ruby expression:

```
y=x.a.b.c.d.e.f
```

Of course, `x` is an object and `a` to `f` are methods defined for a class which matches the return value of the previous method in the chain. Now say that I want to replace the invocation of method `c` by a custom block, i.e. I would like to achieve the effect of

```
temp=x.a.b
temp1=.... (calculate something based on the value of temp)
y=temp1.d.e.f
```

but with using method chaining.

It is of course trivial to define a suitable method to achieve this:

```
class Object

  def pass
    yield(self)
  end

end
```

which would allow me to write something like

```
y=x.a.b.pass {|the_b| .....}.d.e.f
```

Now to my question:

Given that Ruby already has a method for a similar problem (Object#tap), I wonder why it does not have a method similar to the Object#pass which I just explained. I suspect, that either

(a) Ruby already offers a feature like this, and I'm just to stupid to find it, or

(b) What I want to achieve would be considered bad programming style (but then, why?)

Is (a) or (b) correct, or did I miss something here?

Comment: Don't answer it in the question. You can answer your own question as a separate answer. But note that there is already an answer given.

Comment: `y=x.a.b.c.d.e.f` – that kind of expressions are called [train wreck](http://wiki.c2.com/?TrainWreck) ;-)

Comment: @sawa: I didn't see the answer when I updated my post. Thanks for pointing it out; you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) Yes. Ruby already has that. It is called `yield_self`.

(b) No. It is not a bad style.

Comment: It might be worth noting that [`yield_self`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Object.html#method-i-yield_self) was introduced in Ruby 2.5.